# Use object values from one subscribe in another subscribe

Tags: angular

I am trying to develop a feature in a forum and I want to show the profile picture of a user who has asked the question. I am using `mongodb` as my database. To achieve what I want, I need to subscribe values from question collection and pass a `userID` field to user collection to get the desired profile picture. I have tried using loop and passing values from `question.userID` to get the user from user collection. But it is not working. Can someone help me to achieve this. I have posted my code below:

```typescript
ngOnInit() {
  var j = 0;

  this.forumService.getQuestions().subscribe((data) => {
    this.questionData = data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
      this.forumService.getUser(data[j].userID).subscribe((userData) => {
        console.log(userData);

        this.questionData[j].profilepicpath = userData[0].info.profilepicpath;
      })
    }

    console.log(this.questionData[j]);

    j ++;
  });

  this.userID = localStorage.getItem('sessionItem');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two source observables: *of* questions and *of* user data and the latter depends on values of the first.

The code below first flattens observable of array of questions to observable of questions, then it fetches user data from `getUser`, returns object containing all of question data and `profilepicpath` property, and finally joins questions back to arrays of questions.

```typescript
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.forumService.getQuestions().pipe(
    mergeMap(question => question),
    switchMap(question => this.forumService.getUser(question.userID).pipe(
      map(user => ({
        ...question,
        profilepicpath: user.info.profilepicpath,
      })),
    )),
    toArray(),
  ) // subscribe here and unsubscribe on component destroy
}
```

I haven’t tested this code.